# Laravel Array Validation Using IN Rule

Tags: laravel

I am attempting to validate the values of a multiple select form using the IN validation rule. I continue to get the error that my value is incorrect despite being identical to one of the options in the list. I am thinking it has to be the way I am identifying the name in the validator ("step1"). However, I have also used step1.*, step1.0.*, step1*. It will keep giving the "Invalid Response" response which corresponds to the IN error.

Controller

```
public function postQuestionDetailsStep1(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $step1 = $request->input('step1');

        $this->validate($request, [
            'step1' => 'required',
            'step1.0' => 'in:Less than $50,000,$50,000-$100,000,More than $100,000',
        ], [
            'step1.required' => 'You must choose one.',
            'step1.in' => 'Invalid response.',
        ]);
    }
}
```

View

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="step1-option1" name="step1[]" value="Less than $50,000">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="step1-option2" name="step1[]" value="$50,000-$100,000">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="step1-option3" name="step1[]" value="More than $100,000">
```

Javascript

```
$('#step-1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var step1 = [];

    $("input[name='step1[]']:checked").each(function() {            
        step1.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/question/details/1",
        data: {step1:step1},
        error: function(data){
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: 5.6, I believe......

Comment: Since your rule options also have comma, have you try using double quote: `in:"Less than $50,000","$50,000-$100,000","More than $100,000"`? Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575860/escaping-laravel-validation-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma's in your `in` rule, mess up the array you are trying to create. Laravel will read your array like this:

```
['Less than $50', '000', '$50', '000-$100', '000', 'More than $100', '000']
```

You can change the rule to the following, to solve the problem you have with the comma's:

```
in:Less than $50,000,$50,000-$100,000,More than $100,000'
```

to

```
Rule::in(['Less than $50,000', '$50,000-$100,000', 'More than $100,000']);
```

Make sure to `use` the `Rule` class:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Comment: It threw me off to use the Rule class in the validation like that. This works, however. Thank you!